# Calling Recording Above Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to implement Call Recording for one of my client application but above Android 10 I am unable to do is successfully. here is my code classes. Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

I know due to security reasons Google stopped working around Call Recording above Android 10(Q), But I needs this feature for CRM application.

This is my Receiver Class

```
public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.
    // We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber; // because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        // We listen to two intents. The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.
        // We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                int state = 0;
                if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                }
                onCustomCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
            } else {
                // Android 9+
                TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number) {
                        onCustomCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
                    }
                }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        }
    }

    // Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);
    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);
    protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date missed);

    // Deals with actual events

    // Incoming call - goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    // Outgoing call - goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCustomCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if (lastState == state) {
            // No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls. Nothing done on them
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // Went to idle - this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    // Ring but no pickup - a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else if (isIncoming) {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                } else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

This is my service that will work in background to record Audio Calls.

```
class CallRecorderNew : Service(), onCallingListner {
    private lateinit var recorder: MediaRecorder
    private var recordStarted = false
    private var savedNumber: String? = null
    private var lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
    private var isIncoming = false
    var fileName //Obtained by intent
            : String? = null
    var audiouri: Uri? = null
    var file: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL"
    private lateinit var callReceiver: CallReceiver
    private var viewmodal: ViewModal? = null
    override fun onBind(arg0: Intent): IBinder? {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_IN)
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_OUT)
        callReceiver = CallReceiver(this)
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, intentFilter)
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(R.string.app_name.toString() + " is running")
            .setContentText("Please don not use battery optimizations")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.meeting_ic)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
        // return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun stopRecording() {
        if (recordStarted) {
            try {
                recorder.stop()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            recordStarted = false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
        isServiceRunning = true
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val appName = getString(R.string.app_name)
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                appName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }

    private fun saveAudioToExternalStorage(displayName: String): Boolean {
        val recordingCollection = sdk29AndUp {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } ?: MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val contentValue = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, displayName)
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).toInt())
        }
        return try {
            contentResolver.insert(recordingCollection, contentValue)?.also { uri ->
                contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
                    file = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")
                    if (file != null) {
                        recorder = MediaRecorder()
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
                        recorder.setOutputFile(file!!.fileDescriptor)
                        recorder.prepare()
                        recorder.start()
                        MainActivity.history[MainActivity.history.size - 1].recordingUrl =
                            uri.toString()
                    }
                }
            } ?: throw IOException("Couldn't create Media Store Entry")
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }

    }

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"
        const val ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
        const val EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER"
        var isServiceRunning = false
    }

    override fun onIncomingCallStarted(ctx: Context?, number: String?, date: String) {
        isIncoming = true
        savedNumber = number
        saveAudioToExternalStorage("Incoming $savedNumber  $date")
        recordStarted = true
    }

    override fun onIncomingCallEnded(ctx: Context?, number: String?, date: String) {
        stopRecording()
    }

    override fun onOutgoingCallStarted(ctx: Context?, number: String?, date: String) {
        isIncoming = true
        savedNumber = number
        saveAudioToExternalStorage("Outgoing $savedNumber  $date")
        recordStarted = true
    }

    override fun onOutgoingCallEnded(ctx: Context?, number: String?, date: String) {
        stopRecording()
    }

    override fun onMissedCall(ctx: Context?, number: String?, date: String) {
        stopRecording()
    }


    internal class CallReceiver(private val callingListner: onCallingListner) :
        PhonecallReceiver() {
        override fun onOutgoingCallStarted(ctx: Context, number: String, start: Date) {
            val msg = "start outgoing call: $number at $start"
            Log.d("CallReceiverChecker", msg)
            Toast.makeText(ctx.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            callingListner.onOutgoingCallStarted(ctx, number, setDateTime())
        }

        override fun onOutgoingCallEnded(ctx: Context, number: String, start: Date?, end: Date) {
            val msg = "end outgoing call: $number at $end"
            Log.d("CallReceiverChecker", msg)
            Toast.makeText(ctx.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            callingListner.onOutgoingCallEnded(ctx, number, setDateTime())

        }

        override fun onIncomingCallStarted(ctx: Context, number: String, start: Date) {
            val msg = "start incoming call: $number at $start"
            Log.d("CallReceiverChecker", msg)
            Toast.makeText(ctx.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            callingListner.onIncomingCallStarted(ctx, number, setDateTime())

        }

        override fun onIncomingCallEnded(ctx: Context, number: String, start: Date?, end: Date) {
            val msg = "end incoming call: $number at $end"
            Log.d("CallReceiverChecker", msg)
            Toast.makeText(ctx.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            callingListner.onIncomingCallEnded(ctx, number, setDateTime())

        }

        override fun onMissedCall(ctx: Context, number: String, missed: Date) {
            // callingListner.onMissedCall(ctx, number, setDateTime())
            val msg = "missed call: $number at $missed"
            Log.d("CallReceiverChecker", msg)
            Toast.makeText(ctx.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            callingListner.onMissedCall(ctx, number, setDateTime())
        }
    }

}
```

This is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.sten.wit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <!--        <activity-->
        <!--            android:name=".Views.MainActivity"-->
        <!--            android:exported="true">-->
        <!--            <intent-filter>-->
        <!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

        <!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--            </intent-filter>-->
        <!--        </activity>-->
        <service android:name=".CallRecorderNew" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Views.HistoryActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Views.AddMeetingsActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Views.AddClientActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Views.ScheduleMeetingsActivity"
            android:exported="false" /> <!-- <activity -->
        <!-- android:name=".Views.MeetingsActivity" -->
        <!-- android:exported="false" /> -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Views.DetailsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Views.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--        <receiver-->
        <!--            android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"-->
        <!--            android:exported="true">-->
        <!--            <intent-filter android:priority="999">-->
        <!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />-->
        <!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />-->
        <!--                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />-->
        <!--            </intent-filter>-->
        <!--        </receiver>-->

        <service android:name=".CallRecorderNew" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also added permission for  `MediaProjectionManager` but I don't think this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Google is actively disallowing call recording by 3rd-party apps. [Here's](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-killing-call-recording-apps-3155610/) a good write-up for it, but the short answer is that you simply can't record calls any longer